# How to make bootstrap span the unused columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a row with `Bootstrap` that needs only 10 columns. However I would like to use the space left of the unused 2 columns.

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

So I just want it to use the extra space to left right to add space between these elements.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
</div>
```

As you see from the code I just use 10 columns and I need to make use of the extra space.

Comment: You say space between the elements, can't u just do margin: 5px on the divs inside form-group?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/

Answer (score 1):

How about this? add this to your css

```
.text-left
{
     margin-left:2.1%;
     margin-right:1.05%;
     border: 1px solid black;/*if necessary*/
}
```

Comment: this seems to apply it to the entire site. My problem is only in a part of the site that needs only 10 columns

Comment: @AlexTwain: I don't get what you mean. If you only need it for a part of the site, then apply the class .text-left only where you want it. If you are using .text-left class somewhere else, then put this rules in a new class like some '.new-class' and add that class wherever you wanted [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvbbjgap/)

Answer (score 0):

From what i know you can't do that. You have to work around and try to create your custom css classes.

Form example divide 100/5 = 20% and add custom classes to your css like

```
col-md-2-custom{
    width: 20% !important;
}
```

The bootstrap by default uses 12 columns. if your entire site is uses 10 columns you can customize the bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and change the value which says `@grid-columns`

Comment: it's only a part of the site that uses only 10 columns

Comment: I believe there are many ways to work around this. @Justin was also a good answer but don't add it to the text-left class because when ever you use text left the margins won't be right. Create your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a margin on your div's inside `.form-group`. I've tested it, 15px will do.

```
.form-group .col-md-2 {
   margin: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">Unknown</div>
</div>
```

Using offsets will push your content to visually center.

Another thing you can do in order to create padding is to nest your columns inside of other columns. This won't break the grid.

[This codepen gives a good example](http://codepen.io/dyu/pen/Jmjdc) using thumbnnails of images on how nesting columns can allow you to create padding.